# How can I run a job when the server load is low?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, scheduled-task, amazon-ec2

I have a command that runs a disk snapshot (on EC2, freezing an XFS disk and running an EBS snapshot command), which is set to run on a regular schedule as a cron job. Ideally I would like to be able to have the command delayed for a period of time if the disk is being used heavily at the moment the task is scheduled to run.

I'm afraid that using nice/ionice might not have the proper effect, as I would like the script to run with high priority while it is running (i.e. wait for a good time, then finish fast).

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

This is what I ended up going with. It checks /proc/diskstats and runs my job when the current IO activity hits 0, or we timeout. I'll probably have to tweak this when I look at what kind of IO activity our servers actually get in production:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEVICE=sdf

# we want to make a snapshot when IO in progresses reaches this:
LOW_THRESHOLD=0

TIMER=0
MAX_SEC_DELAY=120

# Get the number of IO operations in progress:
ioInProgress(){
    grep $DEVICE /proc/diskstats | awk '{print $12}'
}

# Wait for a good time to run snapshot, else timeout:

while [[ $TIMER -lt $MAX_SEC_DELAY && $(ioInProgress) -gt $LOW_THRESHOLD  ]]; do
    TIMER=`expr $TIMER + 1`
    sleep 0.5
done

# Recording delay required:
echo $TIMER
echo "Executing snapshot"
run-the-snapshot
```

Comment: an alternative maybe use a different io scheduler http://www.redhat.com/magazine/008jun05/features/schedulers/
this may give all process running fairer access to the disk subsystem and stop io starvation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a perl script here http://www.skolnick.org/cgi-bin/list.pl?file=serverload.pl

This should do what you need.

You could probably implement this with a simple shell script that parse uptime, and 
only being execution once the load average has lowered to a certain value.

Beware that if you server is constantly busy, with a run away process, then your
cronjobs will never execute!.

Perhaps a better idea if you have memory is to run you cron jobs at a the lowest OS
priority, thus they will only consume spare resources.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the batch command
Maybe it will fit your needs.

`man batch` for further details (it is a part of the at subsystem)

Comment: Thanks, batch looks great. I decided to go with a homebrew solution since I realized I am more interested in disk IO.

Answer (score 1):

What about writing a little poll/daemon script that, beginning at your scheduled time, checks iostat (vmstat) for low disk activity and continues to check every 5 minutes until the disk activity is lower/below a preset threshold or a period of time has elapsed, whatever comes first?